# Python says my function takes no arguments when it does

Tags: python

I have a function which is called when a button is pressed:

```
def generate_noise():
    var = self.add_snr_textbox.get()
    controller.generate_noise(var)
```

Which corresponds to the function in my controller class:

```
def generate_noise(self, snr):
        print snr
```

However when I try to run it I get the error `TypeError: generate_noise() takes no arguments (1 given)`. Why is this happening?

*More Detail*

`main.py`

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
import controller

root = Tk()
content = ttk.Frame(root)
controller = controller.Controller()


class Main(Frame):

...

def generate_noise():
        var = self.add_snr_textbox.get()
        controller.generate_noise(var)
```

`controller.py`

```
class Controller():
    def generate_noise(self, snr):
            print snr
```

Comment: Please provide enough context to reproduce the problem. I see `self` but I do not see a class declaration.

Comment: You know you have two functions called `generate_noise()` there, right?

Comment: Most likely you are passing `self` implicitly in your function call.

Comment: Something doesn't look right there. What is self referencing in the first function?

Comment: List the full code, as far as I am concerned you've probably placed these two functions in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `Main.generate_noise()` function definition that you give (the one without arguments) references the `self` variable. However, since you do not happen to have a global `self` that you are intending to reference, you are not giving the `Main.generate_noise()` function a way to access `self`. You will need to add `self` as an argument to the `Main.generate_noise` signature so that `Main.generate_noise` can access the instance of `Main` by using

```
def generate_noise(self):
```

instead of

```
def generate_noise():
```

The error that you are getting suggests that you are already calling this function as an instance method somewhere else in your code, so this change should fix both the `TypeError` and the error that you would have had with trying to `self` if you had fixed this another way.

EDIT: Based on the additional information provided, I have clarified names used in this post.

Comment: That fixed it. The `self` variable still confuses me to no end.

Comment: @Nanor In Python, there is no difference between static and instance methods in Python. Instead, the user either includes or doesn't include the `self` in the signature name. If a method is called as an instance (`main = Main()` and `main.generate_noise()`), Python sees this as an instance call and supplies the first argument in the function signature (regardless of what you named it) the class instance. You may also use `Main.generate_noise()` to call it without Python providing a first argument implicitly, or by `Main.generate_noise(main)` to call it as static but provide your own instance.